# Add Record to a different tab

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am **VERY** new to this. I just watched one walkthrough on YouTube while trying to make a "draft room" for my fantasy football league.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z1QLOrOp2cKnabSdWQ8rqAuxgJYBEXqsAY3ygDF3U34/edit#gid=0) is my sheet.

When I click `"Finished"`, I want the info from `F1`, `F2`, and `F3`, to go to the first open row in columns `J:L`. Right now, I have it going to the last open row so it sends it all the way down to the bottom.

I watched a walkthrough so I have no idea what the first 11 lines of code mean below.

```
function setValue(cellname, value) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellname).setValue(value);
}

function getValue(cellname) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellname).getValue();
}

function getNextRow(){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow() + 1;
}

function setTeam1(){
  addRecord(getValue('b2'), new Date(), '1');
}
function addRecord(a, b, c) {
  var row = getNextRow();
  setValue('a'+ row, a);
  setValue('b'+ row, b);
  setValue('c'+ row, c);
}

function finished() {
  addRecord1(getValue('f1'), getValue('f2'), getValue('f3'));
}

function addRecord1(j, k, l) {
  var row = getNextRow();
  setValue('j'+ row, j);
  setValue('k'+ row, k);
  setValue('l'+ row, l);
}
```

I know I need to change the 'getNextRow' but I can't figure out how to get that to work.

Would anyone be able to help me understand the code and how I can get it to work?

Comment: The first 11 lines are just function declarations to be used as convenience functions within another function call. The first sets the value of a cell in the active sheet, the second retrieves a value at a specified cell, and the last function retrieves the next available row.

Comment: The button calls `finished`; which calls `addRecord1`; which calls `var row = getNextRow()`; which calls `getNextRow`; which calls `return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow() + 1;`. **`getLastRow() + 1`** - that's why it is adding data to the last row rather than the first blank row. Now... to think about how better to do it.

Comment: Yeah...If I can get finished to go to a different tab. I can pull columns J, K, and L from that other tab. that would work but idk how to make the 'finished' command addrecord to another tab. Like i said - very new that this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the OP's problem is caused by using the function `getNextRow` which calls `getLastRow()`

The solution is fairly straightforward. Get the last row containing content in Column J, and pass this (plus one) to the `addRecord`function as the row number. The code might look something like this:

```
function sofinished() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
    var jVals = sheet.getRange("J1:J").getValues();
    var jLastRow = jVals.filter(String).length;   
    soaddRecord1(getValue('f1'), getValue('f2'), getValue('f3'),jLastRow+1);
}

function soaddRecord1(j, k, l, r) {
  setValue('j'+ r, j);
  setValue('k'+ r, k);
  setValue('l'+ r, l);
}
```